# What to restart after changing DCOM object permissions via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dcom

I'm using PowerShell to set permissions of a DCOM object successfully.

Though, when using the DCOM object by my software after that, the permission changes are not recognized until I restart the computer.

How can I prevent this restart? Is there a single component/service I can restart after changing the permissions?

I'm using this code to change the permissions:

```
$apiDCOMObj = Get-WmiObject -Query ('SELECT * FROM Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting WHERE Caption = "MyAPI"') -EnableAllPrivileges
$descrLaunch = $apiDCOMObj.GetLaunchSecurityDescriptor().descriptor
$descrAccess = $apiDCOMObj.GetAccessSecurityDescriptor().descriptor
$trusteeObj = ([wmiclass]'Win32_Trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trusteeObj.Domain = "NT AUTHORITY"
$trusteeObj.Name = "NETWORK SERVICE"
$aceLaunch = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$aceLaunch.AccessMask = 11                                            # Mask for Local Launch and Local Activation
$aceLaunch.trustee = $trusteeObj
$aceAccess = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$aceAccess.AccessMask = 3                                             # Mask for Local Access
$aceAccess.trustee = $trusteeObj
$descrLaunch.DACL += [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$aceLaunch
$descrAccess.DACL += [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$aceAccess
$apiDCOMObj.SetLaunchSecurityDescriptor($descrLaunch)
$apiDCOMObj.SetAccessSecurityDescriptor($descrAccess)
```

Comment: Have you ever found an automated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call for [Restart-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service?view=powershell-7).

```
Restart-Service -Name <your_service_name>
```

This will restart the service with the new permissions.

Comment: I can't. Button is greyed-out :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd but a query like

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from Win32_Bios"
```

does the trick for me in refreshing the security on DCOM namespaces.